# Negative Margin Performance Issue

Tags: performance, margin

In the main menu, I have margin-top:-30px. Due to some reason I need to use this. It's working fine. But the issue is it's taking time to download (which is easily visible).

Menu is taking more time than any other element in the page. The menu has margin-top:-30px. When I remove the negative margin, then it downloads immediately.

Can anybody please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to provide much clearer info about your specific problem.

Comment: Menu is taking more time than any other element in the page. The menu has margin-top:-30px. When I remove the negative margin, then it downloads immediately.

Comment: Forget clear info, you need to extract an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and include it.